# How to insert an html tag for the icons

Tags: image

I don't know how to insert an icon into html The little icons that appear above windows in browsers

I try with I try with the tag `Img` In `Head` But it didn't work I want to put a little icon in the page I'm trying to make I just need a helping hand please...

Comment: You should provide more context.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the icons you are talking about are called 'favicons'.

To add a favicon to your webpage, you use the  tag within the  section of your HTML document.

example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Your Page Title</title>
  <link rel="icon" href="path/to/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
  <!-- OR for PNG format -->
  <link rel="icon" href="path/to/favicon.png" type="image/png">
</head>
<body>
  <!-- Your content goes here -->
</body>
</html>
```